# Debugging a dll loaded from within java which is loaded from a browser

Tags: java, debugging, windbg

(My platform is Windows XP SP3. My debugger is windbg, but I've tried Immunity and gdb in cygwin as well.  They all seem to be affected in the same way.  I do not have the source code to either the java applet or the dll in question, so I cannot place debug hooks into the code.)

As per the question title, I am trying to debug a dll which is loaded through java by way of an applet launched within the browser.  I am attaching to the java process directly so that I can gain access to the specific dll being loaded.  However, after a few seconds of the java process being suspended, it terminates and my debugging session is useless.

What is the cause of this termination? A watchdog process within java itself or the browser? Can it be turned off or tuned or left running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch this video [DerbyCon](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=videos/derbycon1/joshua-drake-jduck-exploiting-java-memory-corruption-vulnerabilities) it explains the java applet and watchdog process and some quick tips on getting around it starting around 15:30.

From what he says.  Yes there is a watchdog and no there is no way to turn it off.  He got around it by patching the binary, either on disk or in memory.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Here's a link to the [notes](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-ad-11/Drake/bh-ad-11-Drake-Exploiting_Java_Memory_Corruption-WP.pdf) from the talk as well with the watchdog process described in static detail on page 10.

Comment: I patched the binary and it did not correct the problem.  Obviously something else is going on here.  Thanks for your help, though.